# How to count the number of occurences with different conditions and same foreign key Id?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a table:

Order:

| OrderID | MathBook | ScienceBook | EnglishBook | StudentID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |  | 1 |
| 2 |  | 1 |  | 1 |
| 3 |  |  | 1 | 1 |
| 4 |  |  | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |  |  | 3 |
| 6 |  | 1 |  | 3 |
| 7 |  |  | 1 | 4 |
| 8 |  | 1 |  | 4 |
| 9 | 1 |  |  | 5 |
| 10 |  | 1 |  | 5 |

Before you ask why not design the table to have the books in one row per student, there is an intended business logic that requires the ordered books to be in separate lines.

I want to write a query that can count the same foreign key ID with separate conditions like this.

Expected output:

| AllBooks | Math_Science | Science_English |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |

I am having trouble creating a query to get this output and couldn't find a question similar to this.

Thank you in advance!

Edited: Solution:

Kudos to Gordon!

```
select 
       sum(case when math > 0 and science > 0 and english > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as allbooks,
       sum(case when math > 0 and science > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as math_science,
       sum(case when science > 0 and english > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as science_english 
from (select studentid,
             max(mathbook) as math,
             max(sciencebook) as science,
             max(englishbook) as english
      from [Order]
      group by studentid
     ) s
```

Comment: why all book is 1 , shouldn't it be 3?

Comment: No, only one student in the table has 1 of each book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want combinations -- but in a row.  First aggregate at the student level; then aggregate again:

```
select sum(case when max > 0 and science > 0 and english > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as all,
       sum(case when math > 0 and science > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as math_science,
       sum(case when science > 0 and english > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as science_english
from (select studentid,
             max(mathbook) as math,
             max(sciencebook) as science,
             max(englishbook) as english
      from t
      group by studentid
     ) s
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed... now to brush up on subquery practices